# Sharepoint Designer Tasks

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Any and everytime I want to access the workflow tasks for my workflow by going to Assoication: Task List or Task List it reveals a pulldown that I do not understand.

I dont understand how to use the 'Find the List Item' section

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the form works:

- Data Source - The list to look up
- Field from source - the data from list field you want
- Return type specifies the format of the returned data if applicable.
- Find the list item field - establishes the relational lookup to the above list
- Value - the value of the relational field

It can be read like this, From this list, give me this field returned as this type where this field equals this value. In more context, from the tasks list, give me the outcomes as a string where the tasks list related content ID equals the current item id.

Comment: Gotcha. So the second two fields act like a WHERE clause that doesnt have to be the same field that you are returning. Ok well that does answer the question I will be creating a new question that gets more specific on what I am trying to get done here.